# Does AWS SQS trigger concurrent lambda functions?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS Lambda that is triggered by SQS. Couple dozen lambdas will push message to that SQS. So I was wondering when SQS is flooded with messages does it automatically trigger lambda to create multiple instance of it and handle the messages? Or do I have to configure something else?
Thanks

Comment: I am confused about "create multiple instance" part, do you mean multiple instances of "messages" or multiple instances of "queue" ?

Comment: Good info here: [AWS Lambda function scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html)

Comment: @Ersoy I meant multiple instances of Lambda function so that it could handle tons of messages from the queue

Comment: @jarge thank for the reply, then my answer explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. AWS documentation states [that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html)

> A Lambda function can process items from multiple queues (one Lambda event source for each queue). You can use the same queue with multiple Lambda functions.